# Is there a performance penalty to XX:+PrintClassHistogram?

Tags: java

In our endless battle to improve our heap visibility, we started adding `XX:+PrintClassHistogram` to some of our production services, and while this is super helpful, we started wondering if there's any performance overhead of adding this flag and if there is, if there's a good guesstimate to how much?